# VueJS, can't access "this" or "self" inside the same method

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, methods, axios

currently I stuck on a problem for several hours.
Sadly I haven't found a working solution on this by googling around the world.

The problem is, that I cant't access the "self" or "this" variable inside the same function after pulling the data from an api. I am just getting an 'undefined'.

```
getInvoice(){
  var self = this
  axios
    .get(url)
    .then(response => (self.invoice = response.data.data))

  console.log(self.invoice.invoice_nr) //undefined
},
```

Best regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: the `console.log` is going to fire before the callback in `then`

Comment: add it inside the `.then` function

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I think I got it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this is not Vue JS issue.

Rest APIs are asynchronous in Javascript regardless of the framework you use.

Now, In order to access the data from `Promise`, you need to add it inside the `.then` function.

Have a look at [Axios Docs](https://github.com/axios/axios)

[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

To get your data,

```
getInvoice(){
  var self = this
  axios
    .get(url)
    .then(response => {
        self.invoice = response.data.data;
        console.log(self.invoice.invoice_nr);
    })
},
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your explenation. I think I have now an idea how to deal with such things.

Comment: Glad, I could help!